# How to create a Sub-theme based on a Zen Sub-theme

Tags: theming

I would like to modify the [CTI Flex](http://drupal.org/project/cti_flex) theme but would prefer to keep my changes as maintainable as possible. CTI Flex is already a [Zen](http://drupal.org/project/zen) (7-x.3-x) sub-theme.

I have used the Zen starterkit in the past to create a Zen sub-theme, but never a sub-theme of another sub-theme.

How do I create a sub-theme of using another Zen sub-theme as a start point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't be too hard ... I have a live site running a sub-theme of an AdaptiveTheme sub-theme (Sky). The only thing you have to is create your theme folder and copy the existing `zen-sub-theme.info` to your own `zen-sub-sub-theme.info` and rename the `base theme` value to the zen-sub-theme.

See this page, some magic inheritence occurs with CSS if you define 1 stylesheet for your theme:
http://drupal.org/node/225125

By creating your own .info file you are defining regions / ccs files and theme specific variables. You will also probably want to copy the zen-sub-theme's template.php file as well (renaming the functions to your themes name).